# Save the POST requset result in a global variable

Tags: javascript, axios

How to save the POST requset result in a global variable?
I need to get the name value (value which should be after clicking on btn1) after clicking on btn2
HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='btn1'>
<button type='button' id='btn2'>
```

JS:

```
let name;
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  axios.post('/someUrl', {
      name: 'someName'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        name = response.data.name;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
});

const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(name)
});
```

many thanks for your support!

Comment: create `name` variable as `var name` not as `let name`

Comment: because let will have a limited scope but var will act as global variable

Comment: @DupinderSingh what do you mean by _limited scope_ ? using `let` is perfectly fine here, it will act as global variable since it is declared in global scope. Block scope doesn't means `let` can't be used to declare global variables

Comment: your current code doesn't works?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this code format once, this will help you

```
  let name = axios.post('/someUrl', {
      name: 'someName'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data.name;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
          // doing other something
          return data;
```

Your name will contain the `response.data.name`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/fvsn0ckh/

Make sure your POST request actually returns an object with `name` property. You may try to change `name` to `response.data` instead of `response.data.name` and see what it shows.